# Makefile automatically call `yacc`

Tags: c, makefile, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

Hi I have a makefile like this:

```
# Variables =====================================================================================
PHONY           = 
proj            = 

ALL_FILES   := $(filter $(proj).%,$(shell ls | grep "^$(proj)\.[a-z]*$$"))
LEX_FILE    := $(filter %.l, $(ALL_FILES))
BISON_FILE  := $(filter %.y, $(ALL_FILES))
C_FILE      := $(filter %.c, $(ALL_FILES))
H_FILE      := $(filter %.h, $(ALL_FILES))

BISON_OUT_H := $(subst .y,.tab.h,$(BISON_FILE)) 
BISON_OUT_C := $(subst .y,.tab.c,$(BISON_FILE))
BISON_OUT   := $(BISON_OUT_C) $(BISON_OUT_H)
LEX_OUT     := $(subst .l,.yy.c,$(LEX_FILE))
LEX_TRG     := $(LEX_FILE)
LEX_DEP     := $(LEX_FILE) $(BISON_OUT_H)
GCC_TRG     := $(BISON_OUT_C) $(LEX_OUT) $(C_FILE) 
GCC_DEP     := $(GCC_TRG) $(H_FILE) $(BISON_OUT_H)


CFLAGS      = -g
test:
    @echo $(proj)
    @echo $(ALL_FILES)
    @echo $(LEX_FILE)
    @echo $(BISON_FILE)
    @echo $(C_FILE)
    @echo $(BISON_OUT_C)
    @echo $(LEX_OUT)
    @echo $(GCC_TRG)
    @echo $(GCC_DEP)
# Flex ==========================================================================================
$(LEX_OUT):$(LEX_DEP)
ifneq (,$(LEX_TRG))
    flex --outfile=$@ $(LEX_TRG)
endif

# Bison =========================================================================================
$(BISON_OUT):$(BISON_FILE)
ifneq (,$(BISON_FILE))
    bison -d $<
endif

# Run ===========================================================================================
$(proj).out:$(GCC_DEP)
ifneq (,$(GCC_TRG))
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $(GCC_TRG) -o $@
endif

run:$(proj).out
    ./$<

run_lex:$(proj).out
    @echo "Please type in file names: "; \
    read file; \
    ./$< $$file

PHONY += run run_wc run_lex
# Clean =========================================================================================
clean:
    -rm *.out *.lex *.yy.c *.tab.h *.tab.c *.s
cleansp:
    -rm $(proj).out $(proj).lex $(BISON_OUT) $(LEX_OUT)

PHONY += clean cleansp
# GitHub ========================================================================================
commit: clean
    git add -A
    @echo "Please type in commit comment: "; \
    read comment; \
    git commit -m"$$comment"
sync: commit 
    git push -u origin master

PHONY += commit sync
# PHONY =========================================================================================
.PHONY: $(PHONY)
```

In the current folder I have

```sh
[shore@shore-82b6 flex-bison]$ ls
calc2.c  calc2.h  calc2.l  calc2.tab.c  calc2.tab.h  calc2.y  calc2.yy.c  calc.l  calc.y  ccr.l  lc.l  makefile  Note.md  samples  st.l  wc.l
```

The thing vary confused me is that when I run `make run proj=calc2`, if `calc.y` is changed then the make file will run extra instructions and output to `calc.c` as a result. The following is the shell output:

```sh
[shore@shore-82b6 flex-bison]$ make run proj=calc2
bison -d calc2.y
flex --outfile=calc2.yy.c calc2.l
yacc  calc2.y 
mv -f y.tab.c calc2.c
calc2.yy.c calc2.tab.c calc2.c
```

Notice this will only happen if `calc.y` is changed.

So how should I fix this and letting the makefile run the instructions suppose to be in my makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being bitten by one of make's built-in rules:

```
%.c: %.y
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
         $(YACC.y) $<
         mv -f y.tab.c $@
```

This says, "if I have a file `foo.y` and I want to build a file `foo.c`, here's how to do it".  This is the normal naming convention for building yacc files.

In your situation you have a file `calc2.y` which is the yacc file and another file `calc2.c` which is a normal source file, but make doesn't know that it's a normal source file.

If you want to have your `calc2.y` not be related to your `calc2.c`, and instead have `calc2.y` be related only to `calc2.tab.c`, you'll have to cancel the built-in rule by declaring it without any recipe like this:

```
%.c: %.y
```

Comment: Or change it to run `bison`.